# HOWTO? iOS Device to Device Google Cloud Messaging

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, google-cloud-messaging

I managed to get GCM setup in iOS yesterday.
I was also able to test sending a message directory to my test device.

Today I was going to generalize all this so the iOS app I'm working on could interoperate with the Android counter part via GCM.

That's when I started to get confused.

The iOS GCM Cocoapod provides a couple sendMessage API's that appear to use

```
SENDER_ID@gcm.googleapis.com,
```

where the SENDER_ID is

```
"A sender ID is a project number acquired from the API console,"
```

I don't see how that is going to work.  The Android version uses registrationid's via a http protocol to send messages.  Is that what I need to use?

Any thoughtful guidance?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

GCM on Android and iOS are similar in how they identify specific devices. In both cases the client needs to register with GCM, in doing so it gets a registration ID and that is used to send messages directly to a specific device.

In your case have a look at the callback after registration occurs, you should have a registrationToken that can be used to identify the device for GCM messages.